# docker compose set mongodb bindIp to 0.0.0,0 in /etc/mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, containers

I have the following mongo-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo3:
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo:4.4

    volumes:
      - ~/mongos/data3:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongo-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always        
    command: --replSet "rs1" --bind_ip 0.0.0.0

networks:
  mongo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My objective is to edit the file /etc/mongod.conf.orig in the container in such way that:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  <----- I wish this to be 0.0.0.0


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:  <---------------- should be replication: replSetName: "rs1"

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:
```

unfortunately the command in the docker-compose doesn't apply those changes. I have also tried:

```
entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all","0.0.0.0", "--replSet", "rs1" ]
```

but that doesn't allow the container to run.

Comment: From the [mongo dockerhub page (`dockerhub.com`)](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo): "*... For example, `/my/custom/mongod.conf` is the path to the custom configuration file. Then start the MongoDB container like the following:

`$ docker run --name some-mongo -v /my/custom:/etc/mongo -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf` ...*"

Comment: ...although you shouldn't *have* to make this change; the official mongo image runs `mongod --bind_ip_all`, which accomplishes the same thing (without needing to edit any configuration files).

Comment: @Turing85 got it. works. Thank you. If you wish you can post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @larsks this won't take care of the replication setting though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`dockerhub.com` page for mongo](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) states:

> ...
>
> For example, `/my/custom/mongod.conf` is the path to the custom configuration file. Then start the MongoDB container like the following:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --name some-mongo -v /my/custom:/etc/mongo -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
> ```
>
> ...

Translated to the `docker-compose.yml`, this would mean we write something like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo3:
    container_name: mongo3
    image: mongo:4.4

    volumes:
      - ~/mongos/data3:/data/db
      - ./mongo/config:/etc/mongo
    networks:
      - mongo-network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always        
    command: --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf

networks:
  mongo-network:
    driver: bridge
```

We would then create a folder `mongo/config` within the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml`, and within the folder, we create the `mongod.conf`:

```
mkdir -p mongo/config && touch mongo/config/mongod.conf
```

We can then edit this file to our liking, e.g. setting the bind address and the replication name.